# Find euclidean distance between a tensor and each row tensor of a matrix efficiently in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, euclidean-distance

I have a tensor A of size `torch.Size([3])` and another tensor B of size `torch.Size([4,3])`.

I want to find the distance between A and each of the 4 rows of B.

I'm new to Torch and I reckon a for loop for each of the rows wouldn't be efficient. I have looked into `torch.linalg.norm` and `torch.cdist` but I'm not sure if they solve my problem, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including a specific problem and the code you've tried. Both `torch.cdist(B, A.unsqueeze(0))` and `torch.linalg.norm(B - A, dim=1, keepdim=True)` are efficient solutions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You look for:

```py
torch.norm(A[None, :] - B, p=2, dim=1)
```

- `A[None, :]` resize the tensor to shape (1, 3)
- `A[None, :] - B` will copy 4 times the tensor A to match the size of B ("broadcast") and make the substraction
- `torch.norm(..., p=2, dim=1)` computes the euclidian norme for each column.

Output shape: (4,)